# Probability of drawing a pair in a deck of 162 playing cards.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, conditional-probability, card-games

I was asked this question by a friend of mine and I found it intriguing: if you are dealt an 8 card hand from a deck of three card decks shuffled together, including jokers, what is the probability of drawing at least a pair?
I thought about it a while and concluded that the best way to do this would likely be finding the probability that you were dealt *no pairs* and subtract it from 1. But the jokers really make this a bit more of a difficult question. I figured I would let $$c= \text{the probably of drawing an 8 card hand in which there are no pairs and none are jokers}$$ and let $$j = \text{the probability of drawing an 8 card hand in which there are no pairs and one joker}$$ so that my final calculation (I think) would be $$P=1-c-j.$$

Now to calculate $c$ I would have $\binom{13}{8}$ representing choosing the 8 different ranks, $4^8$ choosing the different suit for each card (or would it be $12^8$ as there are $3$ 2 of hearts, $3$ kings of clubs, etc ?), and finally $\binom{162}{8}$ representing the ways to draw a hand of 8 cards from three standard decks shuffled together. Hence $$c= \frac{\binom{13}{8} 4^8}{\binom{162}{8}}.$$ Now calculating $j$ is where I have some questions. How do I express the possibility I am dealt one and only one joker? I was thinking maybe representing each card pull as a possibility on its own. Without loss of generality, suppose my first card pull was the joker. The odds of that happening are $\frac{6}{162}=\frac{1}{27}$ . But then I have to make sure the rest of the card pulls are non- jokers and non-pairs. Here's the best I got it is virtually the same as finding $c$ but with one less card. That is $\binom{13}{7}$ represents the different ways to pull the $7$ different ranks, $4^7$ represents which suit each card is, and $\binom{161}{7}$ are the ways of pulling $7$ cards from the deck (minus one pulled joker). So $$j= \frac{1}{27}\cdot \frac{\binom{13}{7} 4^7}{\binom{161}{7}}.$$
Calculating $j$ is iffy to me. I was thinking alternatively representing a fraction for each card pull. That is $$j = \frac{1}{27}\cdot \frac{156}{161} \cdot \frac{144}{160} \cdot\frac{132}{159} \cdot \frac{120}{158} \cdot \frac{108}{157} \cdot \frac{96}{156} \cdot \frac{84}{155}.$$ Any help or clarification would be much appreciated. My friends are currently in a hot debate about it :)

Comment: For the denominator $c$, you have 52 buckets containing 3 cards each and 1 bucket containing 6 cards(jokers). SO the total number of ways of picking 8 cards doesn't seem to be $\binom{162}{8}$

Comment: @RahulMadhavan You have $162$ cards total, which is all that matters.

Comment: Say you had 2 cards from 2 packs. AceHearts_{Pack 1}, AceHearts_{Pack 2}, KingHearts_{Pack 1}, KingHearts_{Pack 2} where pack 1 and pack 2 are indistinguishable. The total ways of picking 1 cards from these is not $\binom{4}{1}$, but just 2 no? (You can just pick AceHearts or KingHearts)

Comment: @RahulMadhavan You can distinguish them or not, as you like.  All that matters is that you do the same thing in the numerator and denominator.  Maybe you are commenting on some specific aspect of the OP's calculation?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan Oh wait, I see.  Yes, if you try to make cards of the same rank and suit indistinguishable, then you run into difficulties.  It's best not to make any identifications.

Comment: if two jokers are in the hand, are they considered as a pair ?

Comment: "at least a pair" : Do straights and flushes count as *at least a pair*?  If so, are you allowed to include two cards of the same rank and suit (i.e. two of AceHearts) in the flush?  Also, if straights and flushes do count, is a straight or a flush (still) a 5 card combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability $c$ you get $8$ distinct $13$ non-joker ranks is

$$\frac{156 \cdot 144 \cdot 132 \cdot 120 \cdot 108 \cdot 96 \cdot 84 \cdot 72 }{162 \cdot161 \cdot160 \cdot159 \cdot158 \cdot157 \cdot156 \cdot155}$$

The probability $j$ you get $7$ distinct $13$ non-joker ranks and one joker (in any of the eight positions) is

$$8 \cdot\frac{6 \cdot 156 \cdot 144 \cdot 132 \cdot 120 \cdot 108 \cdot 96 \cdot 84 }{162 \cdot161 \cdot160 \cdot159 \cdot158 \cdot157 \cdot156 \cdot155}$$

So the probability of drawing a pair or more is $1 - c-j \approx 0.90656$

Comment: For $j$ why would you need there $8$? I don't think the position of the joker in the hand matters.

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson $\dfrac{6 \cdot 156 \cdot 144 \cdot 132 \cdot 120 \cdot 108 \cdot 96 \cdot 84 }{162 \cdot161 \cdot160 \cdot159 \cdot158 \cdot157 \cdot156 \cdot155}$ is the probability you draw a joker first.  $\dfrac{156 \cdot 6 \cdot 144 \cdot 132 \cdot 120 \cdot 108 \cdot 96 \cdot 84 }{162 \cdot161 \cdot160 \cdot159 \cdot158 \cdot157 \cdot156 \cdot155}$ is the probability you draw a joker second (the same probability), and so on for all eight possible positions of the joker in the draw.

Comment: Ahh got it thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $1-c-j$, not $(1-c)+(1-j)$.

For $c$ we have $$\frac{\binom{13}{8}12^8}{\binom{162}{8}}$$ and for $j$ we have $$\frac{6\binom{13}{7}12^7}{\binom{162}{8}}$$

Comment: For $j$ why would it be $12$ in $\binom{12}{7}$?... if you pick a joker you still have 13 ranks to choose from.

Comment: And I agree with $1-c-j.$ I have changed it.

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson Typo.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why it is $12^8$ rather than $4^8$?

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson Because there are $12$ cards of any given (non-joker) rank.  There's no reason to treat cards of the same ranks and suit as identical.  That just complicates matters.  Think of them as having different color backs.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I thought that could be the case. Thank you!

Comment: Are we to take it that two jokers also make a pair, though I believe they aren't considered as a rank

Comment: @trueblueanil They are when you play jokers wild.  But it's clear from the OP's attempt that he considers them a pair.

Answer (score 1):

OP hasn't given clarifications whether jokers can be counted as a pair.

Generally, jokers **don't** count as a  pair, so they could range from $0 \;thru\; 6$ in the hand !

Total number of hands is clear, $\binom{162}8$. From this, we need to subtract hands without pairs to get valid number of hands.

Imagine $13$ blocks of *colorful* marbles, red, orange, etc, with each block having $12$ marbles of a specific color, plus one block of $6$ *black* marbles

To eliminate consideration of the black marbles, we shall have to go through case by case. Just as an example, suppose $3$ black are drawn, then only $5$ more need to be drawn from the colorful blocks, and we need to subtract invalid hands accordingly.

The draws with no "regular" pairs to be subtracted from the total ways will be

$$\sum_{k=0}^6\binom6{k}\binom{13}{8-k}\binom{12}1^{8-k} = A,\; say\;$$

And at least one pair = $1- \dfrac{A}{\binom{162}{8}}$

---

**PS:**

**I understand that when "wild", jokers can also be a pair. Then all that needs to be done to the above formula is to work out for** $k = 0 \;to\; 1$